# Include publication done outside PhD study

Tags: thesis

While preparing the thesis, there is a section on list of published journal/papers.

Should I include also some published papers before I started doing the PhD study ?

The topics of the previously published papers are not strictly related to the PhD study and not contributing to the content of the thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like these previous papers were not within the scope of your PhD project, so on that basis should not be mentioned in the thesis.